# Send 15 000 bytes by bluetooth Python - Java

Tags: java, android, python, bluetooth, rfcomm

I would like to send 15 000 caracteres (or 15 000 bytes) by bluetooth with the protocol RFCOMM.

I use this to send data on python :

```
from pylab import*
from rtlsdr import*
from bluetooth import*
import sys

#configure device
sdr= RtlSdr()
sdr.sample_rate=double(sys.argv[3])
sdr.gain=double(sys.argv[2])
sdr.center_freq=double(sys.argv[1])
NFFT=50

#Bluetooth connection

server_sock=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port=server_sock.getsockname()[1]
uuid="94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
client_sock,client_info=server_sock.accept()

while(1):
        samples=sdr.read_samples(256*1024)
        result=psd(samples,NFFT, Fs=sdr.sample_rate/1e6,    Fc=sdr.center_freq*1e6/1e6)
        tab_freq=(result[1]/1e6) 
        value_freq=str(tab_freq)[1:-1]
        value_list=[format(float(v), ".10f") for v in value_freq.split()]
        value_freq2= "\n".join(value_list)
        tab_pxx=result[0]
        value_pxx=str(tab_pxx)[1:-1]
        client_sock.send(value_freq2+'\n'+'\n'.join(value_pxx.split()))
```

And this to get data on java :

```
public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576]; // 20 bits
            int bytes;
            String strRx = "";

            while (running) {
                try {
                    bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                    final String strReceived_freq = new String(buffer,0, bytes);
                    final String strReceived_pxx = new String(buffer,(bytes/2)+1, bytes);
                    //final int samples_sdr=new Integer(buffer,0,bytes);
                    final String strByteCnt = String.valueOf(bytes) + " bytes received.\n";

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                Pxx_value.setText(strReceived_pxx+"\n");    // get data PXX
                                freq_value.setText(strReceived_freq+"\n"); // get data freq

                            // plot value
                          /*  for (int i=0; i<nb_points; i++)
                            {
                                freq[i]=Double.parseDouble(strReceived_freq);
                                pxx[i]=Double.parseDouble(strReceived_pxx);
                                series.appendData(new DataPoint(freq[i],pxx[i]), true,500);
                            }*/

                        }});
```

The problem, After 33 points (NFFT), I can't send more data so my code is rewriting and erase my last data...

How can I fix it ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: please, stop asking the same question again and again

Comment: If the problem is "I can't send more data", you'll need to show the Python code since presumably that's where the problem is, if Python is doing the sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the reason. The Raspberry PI is equiped to Bluetooth 4.1, you can send max **33 bytes for each packet lenght**. If you want to get more, you need to upgrade your bluetooth version (**Bluetooth 4.2 can send 257 bytes max by packet lenght**).

Source : http://www.cypress.com/file/224826/download